# Haproxy + percona xtradb error

Tags: mysql, percona

Всем привет, настраивал по мануалу digitalocean Haproxy для роундробина баз percona, но на сервере haproxу когда я пытаюсь подключиться к базам получаю ошибку.

На haproxy сервере ввожу:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u haproxy_root -p -e "SHOW DATABASES"
```

И получаю ошибку:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2

Конфиг haproxy:

```
    lobal
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 1024
        #chroot /usr/share/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon
        #debug
        #quiet


defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option redispatch
        maxconn 1024
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms

listen galera_cluster
        bind 127.0.0.1:3306
        mode tcp
        option  httpchk
        balance leastconn
        server galera-node01 192.168.0.101:3306 check port 9200
        server galera-node02 192.168.0.102:3306 check port 9200
        server galera-node03 192.168.0.103:3306 check port 9200
```